# Search using cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller

First of all I have a Model user.php which connects to users table.
I have a controller UsersController.

I created a view for search: (filename: index.ctp)

```
<p><?php
echo $this->Form->create("Users", array('action' => 'search'));
echo $this->Form->input("Search Label", array('action' => 'search', 'name' => 'txt_search'));
echo $this->Form->end("Search");
?></p>
```

And this will go to UsersController/search() function

```
function search() {
  if (!empty($this->data))
  {
    $name = $this->data['Users']['txt_search'];
    $conditions = array("User.name Like " => "%$name%");
    $result = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions'=> $conditions));
    $this->set('users', $result);
  }
}
```

And this will load search.ctp

My problem is, when I use the variable $users in search.ctp, it gives me an error Undefined variable: Users [APP\views\users\search.ctp, line 10].

I don't understand.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Put the debug level up to at least 2 to see errors and SQL dump, also put `debug($results)` in your controller to see it's contents before passing it to the view.

Comment: Are you sure that the if code is running and that your query is returning results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying a custom name for your input and then you're checking `$this->data` which will be empty because you're input is not named properly (and does not get auto populated in `$this->data`). Use the following.

> echo $this->Form->input("txt_search", array('label' => 'Search Label'));

A couple of things you should be looking at.

1. Set a default value to your `users` variable so your page doesn't break if they request it directly. Have `$result = array();` at the top and do an `empty()` check on it in search.ctp
2. Why have you specified an action attribute in your input? You don't need that.